# React Context - Using a custom hook or a more provider-centric logic approach

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm setting up the code environment for an upcoming development that requires a global state. Initially, I planned to establish a context for this purpose but found myself unsure about the best approach.

**Importing a custom hook inside the provider:**

Since there's an already tested custom hook relevant to this enhancement, I considered importing it into the provider. This method seems beneficial for modularity and testing, allowing me to reuse the hook beyond the provider's scope while retaining the option to utilize it within a context.

I tried it and it works perfectly fine. I couldn't appreciate any performance issue plus, it's already tested.

I could not find anything related to this approach online, so I'm asking if anyone uses it or perhaps it's not recommended.

```
const FakeDataContext = React.createContext();

const FakeDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const fakeData = useFakeDataLogic();

  return (
    <FakeDataContext.Provider value={fakeData}>
      {children}
    </FakeDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Moving all logic inside the provider:**

The classic one, transferring all logic from the hook directly into the provider and removing the hook file.

```
const FakeDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setData(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <FakeDataContext.Provider value={{ data }}>
      {children}
    </FakeDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**TL;DR**

Is it a good practice to import a custom hook with all the business logic into a provider for managing global state? Any downturns?

I'd love to have opinions on this as I really like the hook-provider approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is compeletely fine to use custom hook inside a provider as it is functional component and supports other predefined hooks.

As long as the rules of hooks are being followed it is completely fine.

It does make more sense to have a custom hook depending on your business logic and code complexity. I have used custom hook inside provider to make my code more readable.